# alternative for arrowEdge of swiftui popover for iOS

Tags: ios, swiftui, popover, ipados

Is it possible for iPadOS to control the position of the popover, to appear on the right side of the view, or under, basically the same behaviour that arrowEdge is offering for macOS.

Right now it is always placed above of the view, like in the picture below. I would like to place it on the right side of the view, where the "red" popover is placed

[image]

The code:

```
struct PopoverExample: View {
    @State private var isShowingPopover = false

    var body: some View {
        Button("Show Popover") {
            self.isShowingPopover = true
        }
        .popover(isPresented: $isShowingPopover, arrowEdge: .trailing) {
            Text("Popover Content")
                .padding()
        }
    }
}
```